# Ionic 2: ngx-loggly-logger

Tags: angular, logging, ionic2

I am using this to log in errors. In my app.components.ts :

```
this.logglyService.push({
          'logglyKey':'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx',
          'sendConsoleErrors' : true,
          'tag' : 'testing'
   });
```

And in the rest of my pages, I import the loggly service and call :

```
this.logglyService.push('Example of error ')
```

But the issue is,  the only errors sent are the ones logged in app.components.ts, but not the other pages.

Am I supposed to include the key and tag on every page with my push?

Answer (score 0):

i made this by a service :

in app.module.ts
define your LogglyService as a provider
then make new service provider and import your service to app.module.ts

```
import { LogglyService } from 'ngx-loggly-logger';
import { MyNewService} from '../providers/MyNewService/MyNewService';
providers: [    
LogglyService,
MyNewService,
...]
```

then inside of your new service

```
import { LogglyService } from 'ngx-loggly-logger';
private loggyTracker = {
                        'logglyKey':'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx',
                        'sendConsoleErrors' : true,
                        'tag' : 'my-tag'
                       };

constructor(private _logglyService:LogglyService, public httpClient: HttpClient) {

}

loggyPush(){ //use this method every where you want in every page
    this._logglyService.push(this.loggyTracker);  //initiate  
    this._logglyService.push('Example of error ');
}
...
```

now you can import your service(MyNewService) in every where you want and call loggyPush() method.

you can also define logglyservice config (key/tag ...) inside of your app.component.ts